# Trocar imagem com evento onmousehover não volta

Tags: php, javascript, magento

Galera, criei um evento me baseando em outros códigos adaptando para o meu para trocar a imagem de uma uma roupa, para outra, só que ela só está "indo" e voltando muito rápido(meio bugada).

Gostaria que ficasse como esse site aqui: https://amaro.com/moda-feminina/blusas
O meu é esse:  duetju.com.br

O meu código está assim:

```
<?php
                                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                                $helper = Mage::Helper('catalog/image');
                                foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {


                                }
                                ?>
                                    <img class="<?php if ($alt_img): ?>em-alt-org<?php endif ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($w,$h) ?>" width="<?php echo $w; ?>" height="<?php echo $h ;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE) ?>';"
onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE) ?>';"/>
```

Oque há de errado nele?
Obrigado

Comment: Você tem esse exemplo seu aí que está meio bugado para ver? Mas algo igual esse site que você passou da pra fazer apenas com CSS....

Comment: desculpa esqueci da loja rs: é essa : http://www.duetju.com.br/

Answer (score 0):

A fonte (o `src` declarado no bloco do evento `onmouseout`) está diferente da declarada no começo...

```
<?php

$initial_img = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                  ->init($_product, 'small_image')
                  ->resize($w,$h);

$hover_img = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                  ->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())
                  ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                  ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                  ->keepFrame(FALSE);

?>

<?php
    echo '<img class="'.$alt_img.'em-alt-org" src="'.$initial_img.'" width="'.$w.'" height="'.$h.'" alt="'.$this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true).'" onmouseover="this.src = \''.$hover_img.'\'" onmouseout="this.src = \''.$initial_img.'\'"/>';
?>
```

---

Porém você podia:

- 1 . Usar estilos CSS em vez de scripts;
- 2 . Não declarar eventos nas linhas HTML.

Comment: vixi, substitui por esse código e bugou tudo :{

Comment: Tenta tirar a aspa antes de `"em-alt-org"` (editado).

Comment: assim: echo '<img class="'.$alt_img.em-alt-org"
?

Comment: @Chead É que nem está lá no código agora... `'<img class="'.$alt_img.'em-alt-org"...`.

Comment: @Chead Corrigi a resposta novamente... eu não tinha notado outros erros antes.

Comment: nada ainda :\ da um erro que só aparece o titulo do modulo

Comment: Já inspeciou os elementos para ver como estava?